# How To Change localhost name in angular 9

Tags: angular

I want to change http://localhost:4200 to default port like  http://1.2.3.4:4200

i am trying add host inside angular.json file in server section but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change host is via angular.json or by cli.

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "projects": {
        "my-project": {
            "architect": {
                "serve": {
                    "options": {
                        "host": 1.2.3.4,
                        "port": 4444
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201 --live-reload-port 49153
```

Check if you didn’t made a mistake in config file.